# Height with xsim's blank-command

Tags: exercises, height, xsim

Currently I'm working with the package xsim and I want to use the blank-command for a gapped text. When my gap text is several lines long the space *between the lines* is too narrow to write. Therefore I wanted to ask, if it is possible to change the height of the blank-command. The goal would be something like this without the setspace.

[image]

instead of

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{doublespacing}
\begin{exercise}
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries \blank{Vokalia} and \blank{Consonantia}, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in \blank{Bookmarksgrove} right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. 
\end{exercise}
\end{doublespacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what is the problem with setspace? It looks like the sensible solution.

Comment: 1. It would be easier and faster if I could implement it with blank/width=2\linespace or something similiar. I was just wondering if this is possible. But I couldn't find anything in the manual.

Comment: but you don't have \blank commands on every line. You would get quite uneven line spacing with your idea.

Comment: 2. Doublespacing does not work *inside* the exercise-environment.

Comment: `\begin{exercise}\doublespacing` works fine for me. And with a current latex you could also do `\AddToHook{env/exercise/begin}{\doublespacing}`.

Comment: Thank you! \doublespacing does the trick **if** there is a empty line after the text. This is a little odd but it works.

Comment: \doublespacing is a paragraph setting so needs  a \par/empty line at the end. But \end{example} inserts it internally. I didn't need an extra one when I tried your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can add `\doublespacing` to the begin of an exercise. Should you be using an exercise template that doesn't output a `\par` at the end (like `xsim`'s `runin` template, for example) you can also add that at the end of an exercise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\xsimsetup{
  load-style = layouts ,
  exercise/template = runin ,
  exercise/begin-hook = \doublespacing ,
  exercise/end-hook = \par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries
  \blank{Vokalia} and \blank{Consonantia}, there live the blind
  texts. Separated they live in \blank{Bookmarksgrove} right at the coast of
  the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by
  their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a
  paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your
  mouth.
\end{exercise}
Text bla blub

\end{document}
```

[image]